# How to modify DOM in Android WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I need to modify pages DOM in Android WebView (hide some elements using id or classname and replace some default impls for functions or CSS styles). I've tried to inject javascript in `WebViewClient.onPageLoaded`:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Finishing ");
        getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(url);
        view.loadUrl("javascript:alert('hello world 2');");
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Finished");
    }
});
```

(showing alert by js here instead of hiding actually). This is not what is desired actually because all the page is shown while it's not loaded.

For some reason js loading in `onPageStarted` does not work - it prevents from loading original URL:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Started ");
            getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(url);

            webView.evaluateJavascript("alert('hello world 1');", null);
            // view.loadUrl("javascript:alert('hello world 1');") prevents too
        }
```

Is it possible to inject JS **before** the page start to load? Any tricks to have callbacks for DOM events in `WebView`?

Answer (score 1):

I solved a problem like this but I solved this in `onPageFinished` method.
You can invisible the webview before DOM manipulation. So users are not affected from process.

```
 public class WebClient extends WebViewClient {
   ...

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById(\"jumbotron-test\").innerHTML = \"\";void(0);");
                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }
```

Comment: "This is not what is desired actually because all the page is shown while it's not loaded."

Answer (score 0):

You can't inject JS in the DOM before the side loads, because the DOM **is** the rendered & loaded website.

You could try to get the source code of the webpage using a `HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();` and a `BufferedReader` and pass it in a `string`. After that you could just modify that string and insert a new `script` tag in the body of the `html`-string:

```
<script>
    alert("Hey, whats up?");
</script>
```

Now your webview can load the string:

```
webView.loadData(yourHtmlString, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

And it should be loaded with the alert-popup.

Comment: This could be the solution but not working sometimes because of original page's scripts. To make it properly i need to parse html and make script chains to make my script running and original page's script running and it's pretty difficult. BTW. the actual aim was not element hiding but creating wrappers or modifying css to make elements invisible